# Unable to make /login POST call from application of marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, post, jwt

I'm working on building the application on the salesforce marketing cloud and facing the issue of making POST /login call to application.

Scenario: We have created a cloud application in Installed package, and given the login and logout URL of our application which is hosted on our server. Now to get the organization ID, /login page will make POST call. But when I do the POST call, I'm getting error. I want to get organization ID here.
can someone help me here.

Once I setup the application, I am making POST call to the Marketing cloud application URL using POSTMAN, and receving 200 ok as HTTP response but unable to find organisation ID.

First Image shows the POST call to the cloud application.
Second image shows the application setup.

[image: This is the reply I am getting when I make POST call to the application]

[image: This is how, I setup my cloud application in marketing cloud]

Comment: Can you edit your post to include some specific details (screenshots, HTTP status codes, status/response messages, etc.) about the errors you're encountering?

Comment: I have included 2 images, one showing the POST call to marketing cloud application and recieving the 200 ok and a HTML page.Unable to find organisation ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your application must read a JWT from the BODY of the Login POST coming from Marketing Cloud.

When Marketing Cloud makes the call to login to your application, the request BODY contains a JWT.  This JWT is an encoded token able to be decoded using the App Signature of your installed package along with a JWT Decoder.  The decoded JWT contains infomration about the Marketing CLoud MID, including the organizationId.